# If statement with "unexpected end of file" on circleCI

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm trying to do a condition in my tests that print `echo "showing dev branch"` if my branch name is `development` but I'm receiving this error

```
if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "development"];  then echo "showing dev branch" fi
bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "development"];  then echo "showing dev branch" fi returned exit code 1
```

See my **circle.yml** below:

```
general:
  artifacts:
    - "test_evidences"
  branches:
    only:
      - development

machine:
  node:
    version: 6.10.3

dependencies:
  pre:
    - curl -L -o google-chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - sudo dpkg -i google-chrome.deb
    - sudo sed -i 's|HERE/chrome\"|HERE/chrome\" --disable-setuid-sandbox|g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - rm google-chrome.deb
    - npm install
    - npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
  override:
    - node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update

test:
  pre: 
    - sleep 60
  override:
    - if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "development"];  then 
        echo "showing dev branch" 
      fi
    - grunt apiTests
    - node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js
    - sed -i -- 's,//,/,g' test_evidences/htmlReport.html
```

Comment: You need a space before `]`.  Also, www.shellcheck.net is really handy for a lot of this type of stuff

Comment: And also semicolon before `fi` if it's being run as a single line (don't know if that's actually happening or if it's just an artifact of the log)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

My new **circle.yml** file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

general:
  artifacts:
    - "test_evidences"
  branches:
    only:
      - development

machine:
  node:
    version: 6.10.3

dependencies:
  pre:
    - curl -L -o google-chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - sudo dpkg -i google-chrome.deb
    - sudo sed -i 's|HERE/chrome\"|HERE/chrome\" --disable-setuid-sandbox|g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - rm google-chrome.deb
    - npm install
    - npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
  override:
    - node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update

test:
  pre: 
    - sleep 60
  override:
    - if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "development" ];  then 
        echo "showing dev branch"; 
      fi
    - grunt apiTests
    - node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js
    - sed -i -- 's,//,/,g' test_evidences/htmlReport.html
```